# CakePHP on GoDaddy Server Stops Intermittently

Tags: php, .htaccess, cakephp

I have a CakePHP application hosted on GoDaddy (its currently in the Alpha phase and will move to Amazon eventually), which works fine for about 5 - 10 page requests, then it stops abruptly and throws an error similar to the following for any page you visit for about 1 - 2 mins and then starts working again.

```
Not Found
Error: The requested address '/organisation/images' was not found on this server.
```

All files are present and the .htaccess settings seem fine by inspection and testing, so it currently has me stumped as to why the application will stop working all of a sudden every few minutes. Checking the CakePHP logs also only just reveals the same errors

I need help determining what might be causing this symptom.

Comment: check your `app/tmp/log` files for stack traces and _add examples to the question_ - sounds like something to do with caching or permissions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was due to caching as @AD7six mentioned. I had two projects on the same server with the same default cake cache settings so they were overwriting one another and causing conflicts. I changed the following line in the cake core.php to be different for each of the projects.

```
// Prefix each application on the same server with a different string, to avoid Memcache and APC conflicts.
$prefix = 'myapp_';
```